# Delete second EFI System Partition (same disk as the first ESP)

Tags: multi-boot, uefi, arch-linux

I recently installed Arch Linux in dual boot alongside an existing Windows 10 (Windows 10 was pre-installed on my Dell XPS 7590) in UEFI.

When it came to partitioning, I've created a 300MB partition for ESP (EFI System Partition). I installed the whole system, and I'm successfully able to boot (with Grub) to Arch or Windows 10.

However, there was **already an ESP** (probably created by the Windows 10 install) that I could have re-used instead of creating a new one. My NVME disk is now formatted like (I only kept the interesting details) :

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1 # Windows ESP
  └ EFI
    ├ Boot
    │ └ bootx64.efi
    └ Microsoft
      └ Boot
        └ bootmgfw.efi

/dev/nvme0n1p8 # Arch ESP
  └ EFI
    └ arch
      └ grubx64.efi
```

I've read that, even if it works, having 2 ESP on the same disk is not a good idea :

- From https://superuser.com/a/688758 :

> Windows officially supports just one ESP per disk [...]. I don't know about Windows 8, but the Windows 7 installer will flake out if it sees more than one ESP on a disk; the installation will proceed part of the way and then fail.

- From https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=16261695 :

> There can only be one ESP and that's in the spec. You can have multiple partitions each assigned as /boot for a different OS, but there can only be one ESP which is used by the firmware to store its settings, etc.
>
> The [EFI spec](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/doc/product-specification/efi-v1-10-specification.pdf) is officially silent about the presence of multiple EFI system partitions on non-removable hard drives, but explicitly forbids multiple ESPs on removable disks, per §11.2.1.3:
>
> *For removable media devices there must be only one EFI system partition, and that partition must contain an EFI defined directory in the root directory*
>
> But in practice, Bad Things (TM) happen if you have more than one ESP on the boot disk.

I don't know if the first point still applies (Windows 10), but I've also read (I can't remember where) that sometimes Windows updates could mess up if 2 ESP are present on the same disk.

As a result of these "fears", and since my system is not already fully setup, I've decided to reinstall Arch Linux (keeping the dual boot), and using the same ESP (`/dev/nvme0n1p1`) created by the Windows install this time.

But before starting the reinstall process, I'm wondering : **is it safe to remove the `/dev/nvme0n1p8` partition (second ESP used for Arch)?** In the BIOS, I've noticed that, in *Boot sequence*, there are currently two options :

- Windows Boot Manager
- arch

I can see the same result when running `efibootmgr -v` :

```
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager HD(1,GPT, ...)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)
Boot0003* arch HD(8,GPT,...)/File(\EFI\arch\grubx64.efi)
```

So, if I understand correctly (tell me if I'm wrong), it looks like removing the 8th partition will only remove the "arch" option, and keep **only** the "Windows Boot Manager" on the 1st partition intact. Am I right?

I've removed the `esp` flag on this partition with `parted` ([`set 8 esp off`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_node/set.html)). I'm able to boot into Windows (via Grub, or by defining "Windows Boot Manager" as the first option in the BIOS *Boot Sequence* screen). Now, I can remove the 8th partition from Windows disk management utility in Windows (not grayed anymore since I've set the `esp` flag off), but **is it really safe?** Will I still be able to boot into Windows after?

I'm also confused about Grub, what will happen after the removal of the 2nd ESP?

Comment: My choice: I would delete the EFI in `nvme0n1p8` > install GRUB in `nvme0n1p1` > mount it as `/boot` > `grub-install` and `grub-mkconfig` can automatically detect WIndows bootloader.

Comment: @Biswapriyo thanks for your comment. After deleting the partition `nvme0n1p8` (and if I don't install Grub for now), should I always be able to boot into Windows? Actually, I would like to restore my system as it was when I booted it for the first time (only Windows) to be able to reinstall Arch cleanly after that.

Comment: From the folder structure, I think you can go without GRUB. Deleting, ESP in `p8` may not affect Arch nor Windows.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Thanks. I think I understand for Windows, because there is still the ESP in `p1`, but what about Arch? Why deleting ESP in `p8` may not affect Arch? If I delete `p8`, `grubx64.efi` will disappear. Could you elaborate please? I'd like to understand why deleting ESP in `p8` may not affect Arch :)

Comment: Becasue generally ESP (fat32) is generally different partition from Arch's root partition (ext4). You can install GRUB later to make it dualboot/chainload with Windows bootloader.

Comment: @Biswapriyo thanks for your help. I've just deleted the `p8` (and other Arch-only partitions) and can successfully boot into Windows.

Comment: grubx64.efi will not work anyway on any normal code for UEFI, since that is not correct name for the bootloader. Rename for bootx64.efi